# Android, color an item of a listView

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView that uses the

```
SimpleAdapter
```

Each element of this list contains 2 textView

I wanna color(change the backgroud color) an item of this list, how can I do?

Comment: post what you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the background color of the whole view (not just the textview) and using a very simplistic approach you would have this call:

```
private void setupAdapter() {
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, resource, from, to) {
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View superView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            superView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black); // or whatever color 
            return superView;
        };
    };
    // use the adapter as: myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be done using android selector (xml). see the example [here](http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way to create custom SimpleAdapter class which overrides getView method and there you make an background change depending - I guess - on some condition.